# GGplot is refusing to change the colors of my row annotation

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, pheatmap

There are some issues with my ggplot chart that I can't seem to fix.

```
# as you may geuss from the file name I have provided this matrix below
vis.matrix <- read.csv("csvfileprovidedbelow.csv")
    
# setting up annotation_row
cell_df <- data.frame ("Cells" = c(rep("Putative Engram Cell", 10), rep("Random Cell",10))
    )
rownames(cell_df) <- rownames(vis.matrix)
cell_df$Cells <- as.factor(cell_df$Cells)
    
#setting up colors
newCols <- colorRampPalette(grDevices::rainbow(length(unique(cell_df$Cells))))
annoCol <- c("2AFE00", "ACACAC") # green and grey
names(annoCol) <- levels(cell_df$Cells)
annoCol <- list(category = annoCol)
    
color=colorRampPalette(c("navy", "white", "red"))(50)
        
#plotting
pheatmap(vis.matrix,cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols=F, annotation_row = cell_df,
                 annotation_names_col = F, scale = "column", color = color, 
                 annotation_row_colors = annoCol,
                 show_rownames = F)
```

**Result**
For some reason the Cells are not the colors I selected, you can search those colors here: https://www.color-hex.com/

Don't know why ggplot is ignoring the input I'm giving it.  Also would like to remove the word "Cells" beside the color bars on the graph, it's unescessary the legend already explains what it is.
[image]

**Variables as csv's for reproduction(copy and paste!)**

vis.matrix is here:

```
"","LINGO1","ARC","INHBA","BDNF","MAPK4","ADGRL3","PTGS2","CHGB","BRINP1","KCNK1"
"P57_CATCGGGCATGTCGAT",-0.368245729284319,3.47987283505039,2.94634318740768,5.57309275653906,1.28904872906168,5.3650511213102,-0.368245729284319,2.25850383984707,4.60363764575367,-0.368245729284319
"P57_GAAGCAGGTAAAGGAG",-0.384074162377759,4.36118508997518,3.70326968156081,4.89874111968957,1.65959775959153,4.36118508997518,-0.384074162377759,-0.384074162377759,4.89874111968957,2.85506919772029
"P57_TGACTTTTCTTTACAC",-0.357194851773428,2.40812492004642,3.13225019258772,5.67855340720666,-0.357194851773428,3.13225019258772,-0.357194851773428,4.87697271476829,1.38752767040715,-0.357194851773428
"P57_CTAGAGTGTCCGACGT",1.50110424640379,3.34315724311024,2.57863617381809,6.67240079339861,3.34315724311024,3.93616585502151,-0.340948750302666,1.50110424640379,5.77821885172796,3.34315724311024
"P57_CCTTACGTCCAAGTAC",-0.381478022176755,4.73256922534426,2.17554560158375,6.70465771162764,1.23182426263886,3.36449387848259,-0.381478022176755,2.17554560158375,4.45842883227008,3.36449387848259
"P57_ATCCGAAGTGTGACCC",2.60172319423431,1.50562420175544,-0.36816940232616,5.57161579079479,1.50562420175544,3.37941780583703,-0.36816940232616,3.37941780583703,4.47551679831591,3.98264461101114
"P57_TCCACACAGCTCCTCT",-0.364903374339472,2.59101007342497,2.59101007342497,5.23001785519025,-0.364903374339472,3.36504411201368,-0.364903374339472,1.5000703688371,1.5000703688371,-0.364903374339472
"P57_CTGAAGTGTGCTTCTC",-0.384690873645543,3.35025193111807,2.83241374986762,4.71429931551947,3.35025193111807,3.35025193111807,-0.384690873645543,3.35025193111807,2.16480422093696,2.16480422093696
"P57_CTGATAGAGAATCTCC",1.6886646742164,2.87694996247181,-0.342722443403036,7.39148929746973,1.6886646742164,5.75143890945527,-0.342722443403036,5.75143890945527,4.37401237658979,-0.342722443403036
"P57_GGAGCAACATACAGCT",-0.351186802480077,1.4651606822983,1.4651606822983,5.40649850082577,-0.351186802480077,4.34400333395122,-0.351186802480077,1.4651606822983,5.09785565185506,1.4651606822983
"A57_CGTCTACCAGACGCAA",-0.229651158962319,-0.229651158962319,-0.229651158962319,-0.229651158962319,-0.229651158962319,3.72717582194343,-0.229651158962319,-0.229651158962319,-0.229651158962319,-0.229651158962319
"P57_GTTCGGGCAATGGACG",-0.269219507178484,-0.269219507178484,-0.269219507178484,-0.269219507178484,-0.269219507178484,4.26241026631276,-0.269219507178484,-0.269219507178484,-0.269219507178484,-0.269219507178484
"P56_GGTATTGTCATGTCTT",-0.294887130864939,-0.294887130864939,-0.294887130864939,-0.294887130864939,-0.294887130864939,5.06808977241301,-0.294887130864939,-0.294887130864939,-0.294887130864939,-0.294887130864939
"A67_AAATGCCAGATAGTCA",4.03836820795661,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977,-0.211281061058977
"P76_CCCTGATAGAGGACTC",-0.507269585219581,-0.507269585219581,-0.507269585219581,1.90264065061749,-0.507269585219581,4.86614536666517,-0.507269585219581,1.40253909173334,-0.507269585219581,0.697685532698955
"P56_GATCGATTCCGTCAAA",2.00727896845415,-0.313514850319463,-0.313514850319463,2.00727896845415,-0.313514850319463,3.36485632434217,-0.313514850319463,-0.313514850319463,-0.313514850319463,-0.313514850319463
"P57_GCTGCAGCATAGGATA",2.32839123926114,-0.289105834618761,-0.289105834618761,-0.289105834618761,-0.289105834618761,2.32839123926114,-0.289105834618761,-0.289105834618761,-0.289105834618761,4.94588831314104
"P82_AGGATAACATAGGTTC",1.39699437520094,-0.501641808549684,0.696264250985952,1.39699437520094,-0.501641808549684,4.49353661848721,-0.501641808549684,-0.501641808549684,1.89417031052159,-0.501641808549684
"P82_CCAAGCGTCCGGCTTT",-0.328980171926236,-0.328980171926236,-0.328980171926236,4.08682708745919,-0.328980171926236,1.87892345776647,-0.328980171926236,-0.328980171926236,4.08682708745919,-0.328980171926236
"P57_CAGCGACCATGTCCTC",-0.316475979591103,-0.316475979591103,-0.316475979591103,2.18079240270816,-0.316475979591103,6.13886914288907,-0.316475979591103,2.18079240270816,-0.316475979591103,4.67806078500742
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pheatmap` is *not* ggplot. It is drawn using grid graphics.

Anyway, you would pass the color specification as follows:

```r
pheatmap(vis.matrix, cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols=F, annotation_row = cell_df,
         annotation_names_col = F, scale = "column", color = color, 
         annotation_colors = list(Cells = c("Putative Engram Cell" = "#2AFE00", 
                                            "Random Cell" = "#ACACAC")),
         show_rownames = F)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, I though ggplot2 underlaid pheatmap.

Comment: Which option do I use to turn off the text reading "Cells" under the colored bars for row annotation in the bottom left of the image?  I'm reading the documentation but it's not clear which option to set to false.

Comment: It's `annotation_names_row = F`